# Can we prove any statement in the first order logic operating only in the space of prenex normal forms?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

Let's assume that we have a set of statements written in first order logic (axioms and maybe some proven theorems). Now we want to prove that a given "new" statement is true.

My naive approach to the prove would be like follows:

1. Take all statements that are used as inputs (axioms and proven theorems) and connect them with `and` (conjunction) so that we get just one large statement (sentence in FOL).
2. Bring this "large" statement to a prenex normal form using simple deterministic rules (for example as explained [here](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Elkari/prenex.pdf)).
3. Similarly, bring the statement that you want to prove to the prenex normal form as well.

Now, use formulas like:

$\forall x. P(x) \implies \exists x . P(x)$

to show that the "output" expression (written in the prenex normal form) follows from the "input" expression (also written in the prenex normal form). In other words, we will use only transformations that preserve the prenex normal form. So, all our derivations will be in the space of the prenex normal form.

So, now my questions is if such an approach would work. I guess that it is not the case, because it would be too simple. So, the second part of the question is: Why this approach would not work? Where can if fail?

Answer (score 0):

That's a famous problem, called the Entscheidungsproblem. "is first order logic decidable?", that is: if we're given a sentence is there an effective method for determining whether or not it is valid?

Turing and Church proved (the first with his machines the second with lambda calculus) that it is not the case.

---

Roughly:

By the Church-Turing thesis every computable function is Turing-computable.
Also consider the Halting Problem: the function $h(e,w)$ that halts with output $1$ if the Turing-machine described
by $e$ halts on input $w$ and outputs $0$ otherwise, is not Turing-computable.

The strategy is to reduce the decision problem to the Halting problem.

So we create two Turing-machines:
For every input $w$ and a Turing Machine $M$;
one sentence is $\tau (M,w)$ which represents the instructions of $M$ and the input $w$ another sentence is $\alpha (M,w)$ expressing "M eventually halts" such that:
$$\vDash \tau (M,w) \to \alpha (M,w) \;\; \text{iff} \;\; \text{M halts for input}\, w$$

Proving that reduces the decision problem to the halting problem, all that remains to do is to code first order logic into numbers so that Turing machines can operate on them.

Comment: but I am asking not about existence of "effective methods". My questions is why is it hard to generate a proof by transforming one sentence written in prenex form until it is get identical into another sentence in prenex form (the one that we want to prove). There is also a restriction that on our way from "input" sentence to "outoput" sentence we should always remain in prenes normal form.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here, can you please rephrase what you said? keep in mind that any formula of FOL is equivalent to some formula in PNF, so the question of decidability: "Can we prove any statement in the first order logic operating only in the space of prenex normal forms?", can be answer by referring to the overall FOL system.

Comment: I try to reformulate. I wonder if there is a limited set of transformations rules defined on PNF, such that by applying them one one, we can transform from the initial PNF statement to the PNF statement that we can prove. I can imagine that some of there rules involve manipulation of quantifiers some other change expressions after quantifiers and, maybe, there are other rules that do both at the same time.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure on what you're asking. Are you asking us whether it is possible that given a formula in PNF $Q_1 Q_2... Q_n (\Phi)$, where $Q_i$ is a quantifier, we can rearrange it to an equivalent formula still in PNF, say: $Q_1 Q_2 ... Q_m (\Psi)$, that can be shown to be valid? If so then the answer is no, because FOL is not decidable.

Comment: Incidentally a FOL that is limited to monadic (one-place) predicates IS decidable after we do the opposite operation of the usual transformation into PNF; that is we bring all the quantifiers in until no quantifier is in the scope of another quantifier. We then use a (sort of) truth table on those elementarily-quantified formulae.

Comment: I would like to have a set of transformations such that when each of them, if applied to a formula in PNF, gives a new formula in PNF which follows from the original one. So, the "new" formula should not necessarily be equivalent to the "old" formula, it just need to follow from the "old" one. And I want that the mentioned set of transformations is complete, meaning that any formula that follows from the original formula can be obtained by application of those transformations only.

Comment: Oh now I understand! you want a logic that preserves PNF. It's not that hard really, you just need normal natural deduction augmented with the procedures to bring the quantifiers out :) and you only allow the proof to end when the conclusion is also in PNF.

Comment: I don't know about your "completeness" though.